# ExpressJs URL Parameters and Routing

Tags: javascript, express

I am a newbie in expressjs so , I am working on an app and I need to put in the url the user name . I am not sure how to add it.
So I have 2 files one in routes with the following code

```
exports.user = function (req, res) {
sess = req.session;
if (sess.cocoToken != undefined || sess.cocoToken != null) {
    client.get(baseUrl + "/feed/", {headers: {"Authorization": "Token " + sess.cocoToken}}, function (data3, response3) {
        if (response3.statusCode == 200) {
            req.session.items = data3;

            client.get(baseUrl + "/api/advice/", {headers: {"Authorization": "Token " + sess.cocoToken}}, function (data4, response4) {
                if (response4.statusCode == 200) {
                    req.session.items = data4;
                    res.render('user', {
                        title: req.session.profile.username,
                        classname: 'feed',
                        profile: req.session.profile,
                        feedIitems: req.session.items,
                        advices: req.session.items
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    console.log(req.session.profile);
} else {
    res.redirect("/logout")
}
```

};

and in app.js I call the route

```
app.get('/user', routes.user);
```

Now how do I get to put the user name in the url?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

```
req.param('tagId')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer please, where to put it ? maby some documentation and an example

Comment: When you access the API pass the params in the url like "http://example.com/user?username=user2991920" then in your function in which you access the req and res variables access the username param like  var username=req.param('username')

Answer (score 0):

You can pass username as query parameter as this is a GET request like this http://example.com/user?username=user2991920.

In your route you can access it by using `req.query.username`

```
exports.user = function(req, res) {
    // req.query.username will have query username
}
```

You don't need to modify `app.get('/user', routes.user);`

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
sess = req.session;
if (sess.cocoToken != undefined || sess.cocoToken != null) {
    client.get(baseUrl + "/api/user/" + req.params.id + "/", {headers: {"Authorization": "Token " + sess.cocoToken}}, function (user, response3) {
        if (response4.statusCode == 200) {
            req.session.items = advices;
            res.render('user', {
                title: user.profile.username,
                classname: 'feed',
                user: user
            });
        }

    });
}
```

});